# Unknown column '$a' in 'where clause'

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

i want to fetch data from database by using a variable string.it shows error

**"Unknown column '$a' in 'where clause'"**

```
String a=request.getParameter("from");

ResultSet resultset=  statement.executeQuery("select * from flight where f = $a") ;
```

Comment: pls hlp me wth this

Comment: Incomplete code

Comment: i js copied line that shows error

Comment: what is the correct syntax to use that variable ?

Comment: As this has nothing to do with JavaScript, I've removed the tag.

Comment: Don't edit the question long after-the-fact such that it invalidates existing answers. I've rolled back that edit. If you don't understand the answer, you can post a comment on it saying what you don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the value of the `a` variable where you have `$a`, you need to use a prepared statement and fill it in:

```
String a = request.getParameter("from");
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement( // Create a prepared statement
    "select * from flight where f = ?"              // Using ? for where the
);                                                  // parameter goes
ps.setString(1, a);                                 // Fill in the value (they
                                                    // start a 1, oddly)
ResultSet resultset = ps.executeQuery();            // Execute the query
```

Note that even though it's a string, you don't put quotes around the `?`. The `PreparedStatement` handles that for you at the DB driver level, in a way that's safe from [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com).